# Parsing C File I/O

Tags: c, file-io

I need to extract text from File Io without comma and comments.

Output of this program should be:

```
0 5 0 0/ 0 0 0 7 / 0 4 0 0
```

Can annyone help? This is the code I have and the file content:

```
array[3][3] = {    
//****************************************    
/*0*/       //      
/*0*/       {   0,      5,      0,      0},     
//****************************************    
/*1*/       //     
/*1*/       {   0,      0,      0,      7},    
//****************************************    
/*2*/       //     
/*2*/       {   0,      0,      4,      0},     
//****************************************    
};
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    const char s[250] = ",";
    char *token;
    if(fp != NULL)
    {
        char line[200];
        while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)
        {
                    token = strtok(line, s);
                    while (token != NULL)
                    {
                        printf ("%s ",token);
                        token = strtok (NULL, s);
                    }
        }
     } else {
        perror("file2.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: How to remove the comments And print : 0 5 0 0/ 0 0 0 7 / 0 4 0 0

Comment: Do you just want to print the numbers or want to store them in an array?
 If it is the latter, there are no `double` arrays in your program. Did you mean to have the  `array` in your program instead of in the text file?

Comment: @Lauren1265 from your last comment: then your question is misleading. You should [edit] the question ans mke clear what exactly you want.

Comment: Ok. I edited it. Thank you for advice

Comment: @Lauren1265 please learn how to use markup for formatting text.

Comment: regarding: `FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");`  always, immediately, check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  if not successful, then call `perror()` to output to `stderr` the enclosed text and the reason the system thinks the operation failed..  Then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  to exit the program.   Then no need for the `if(fp != NULL)`

Comment: is that `array[3][3] = { ` , etc actually in the input file content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening the file, use `fgets()` to read and ignore the initial lines which does not matter. You could use a function like

```
void skiplines(FILE *f, char *str, int n)
{
    while(n>0)
    {
        if(fgets(str, 100, f)==NULL)
        {
            return;
        }
        if(str[strlen(str)-1]=='\n')
        {
            --n;
        }
    }
}
```

where `f` is the `FILE` pointer, `n` is the number of lines to be skipped and `str` is the character array to which `fgets()` writes data.

[`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) return `NULL` if it fails.

In the calling function, they are declared like

```
char str[100];
FILE *fin=fopen("in3.txt", "r");
if(fin==NULL)
{
    perror("File not found.");
}
```

Note that `fopen()` returns `NULL` if some error occurred while trying to open the file.

Now skip the first few lines till the first line that need to be processed is reached.

```
skiplines(fin, str, 7);
```

After this, `str` will have the last line read which is the line from which we need to extract the numbers.

Use `sscanf()` to convert the numbers

```
sscanf(str, "%*[^{]{ %d, %d, %d, %d", &num[0], &num[1], &num[2], &num[3]);
```

where `num[]` is an integer array.

`%[^{]` will keep scanning till and excluding a `{` character. The `*` is for assignment suppression meaning that it will not be assigned anywhere.

And you have

```
num[0] -> 0
num[1] -> 5
num[2] -> 0
num[3] -> 0
```

Now use a loop for the rest.